# Validation inside a class property

Tags: c#

The code is as follows:

```
public class MyEvent
{
    public string EventTitle { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public bool IsInsideSameMonth
    {
        get
        {
            // No code is bug-free, so we assume this situation may occur somehow.
            if (StartDate > EndDate)
            {
                // And when this occurs, we want to halt the application by throwing exception to prevent further potential damage.
                throw new MyEventException("Start date is not supposed to be greater than end date.");
            }

            return (StartDate.Year == EndDate.Year && StartDate.Month == EndDate.Month);
        }
    }

    public void Validate()
    {
        if (StartDate > EndDate)
        {
            throw new MyEventException("Start date is not supposed to be greater than end date.");
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EventTitle))
        {
            throw new MyEventException("Title cannot be empty.");
        }
    }
}

public class MyEventException : Exception
{
    public MyEventException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }
}
```

It might seem redundant that I perform `StartDate > EndDate` validation inside the `IsInsideSameMonth` property. I just prefer being on the safe side. But it feels as if I am doing something wrong but I cannot describe it.

Is this a good practice? Please share your valuable experience and thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use Auto-implemented property. You should instead use a backing private field and then check while setting the property like:

```
private DateTime _StartDate;
public DateTime StartDate
{
    get { return _StartDate; }
    set
    {
        if (value > _EndDate)
        {
            throw new MyEventException("Start date is not supposed to be greater than end date.");

        }
        else
        {
            _StartDate = value;
        }
    }
}

private DateTime _EndDate;
public DateTime EndDate
{
    get { return _EndDate; }
    set { _EndDate = value; }
}
```

Your current code would allow the user to set `StartDate` to any value and you will only realize if you check your property `IsInsideSameMonth`.

Answer (score 0):

For the EventTitle you could declare a backing field and make the validation inside the setter of the property. Something like this:

```
string eventTitle;
public string EventTitle
{
    get
    { 
        return eventTitle;
    }
    set
    {
        if(!IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            eventTitle = value;
        else
            throw new MyEventException("Title cannot be empty.");
    }
}
```

As for the DateTime objects you could follow the same path:

```
private DateTime startDate;
public DateTime StartDate
{
    get 
    {
        return startDate; 
    }
    set
    {
        if (value > EndDate)
        {
            throw new MyEventException("Start date is not supposed to be greater than end date.");
        }
        else
        {
            startDate = value;
        }
    }
}

private DateTime endDate;
public DateTime EndDate
{
    get 
    { 
        return endDate; 
    }
    set 
    {   
       endDate = value; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to control values when the properties are set, so you need to convert your automatic properties to old style (properties with private field) and put your checking there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Microsoft property design guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006.aspx).

Here is an example checking the values when setting, throwing if invalid. I've also defined functions for validation to reduce redundant code (in case you want to change your validation or error messaging- it will be in one location).

```
public class MyEvent
{
    public bool IsInsideSameMonth
    {
        get
        {
            return (StartDate.Year == EndDate.Year && StartDate.Month == EndDate.Month);
        }
    }
    private string _EventTile;
    public string EventTitle
    {
        get { return _EventTile; }

        set
        {
            ValidateTitle(value); // this will throw if invalid and leave the value of _EventTitle unchanged
            _EventTile = value;
        }
    }

    private DateTime _StartDate  = DateTime.MinValue;;
    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get { return _StartDate; }
        set
        {
            ValidateDates(value, EndDate); // this will throw if invalid and leave the value of _StartDate unchanged
            _StartDate = value;

        }
    }

    private DateTime _EndDate  = DateTime.MaxValue;;
    public DateTime EndDate
    {
        get { return _EndDate; }
        set
        {
            ValidateDates(StartDate, value); // this will throw if invalid and leave the value of _EndDate unchanged
            _EndDate = value;
        }
    }

    private void ValidateDates(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        if (start > end)
        {
            throw new MyEventException("Start date is not supposed to be greater than end date.");
        }
    }

    private void ValidateTitle(string title)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
        {
            throw new MyEventException("Title cannot be empty.");
        }
    }

    public void Validate()
    {
        ValidateDates(StartDate, EndDate);
        ValidateTitle(EventTitle);
    }
}

public class MyEventException : Exception
{
    public MyEventException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }
}
```